# How to define C++ basic type, which would NOT comply to the original type?

Tags: c++, function, types, specialization

If I defined type like this:

```
typedef int MyType;
```

Then I have following methods:

```
void MyFunc(int i) { dosomething; };
void MyFunc(MyType i) { dosomething; };
```

But then you have a compiler error, because MyType is actually int, so the function is defined twice. Is there a way to define MyType so that it would work like the original type (e.g. int as in the example), but it would require specific implementation for all functions like this?

*In particular, I'm using "bool" as "char", but I'm pretty sure I could come up with several examples like this*

Comment: A typedef is just an alias, not a new type.  If you want a new type, then define a struct or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to create your own `int` type is with [`boost::operators`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/operators.htm), then you can easily define a fully `int`-like `MyInt` like this:

```
class MyInt
: boost::operators<MyInt>
{
  bool operator<(const MyInt& x) const;
  bool operator==(const MyInt& x) const;
  MyInt& operator+=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator-=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator*=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator/=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator%=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator|=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator&=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator^=(const MyInt& x);
  MyInt& operator++();
  MyInt& operator--();
};
```

Now your function overloads properly:

```
void MyFunc(int i) { dosomething; };
void MyFunc(MyType i) { dosomething_else; };
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a base class:

```
typedef struct U32_ID
{
    explicit U32_ID( U32 a )
        : m_ID( a )
    {}

    explicit U32_ID( const U32_ID& A )
        : m_ID( A.m_ID )
    {}

    bool operator==( const U32_ID& A )  const
    {
        return ( this->m_ID == A.m_ID );
    }

    bool operator==( const U32 A )      const
    {
        return ( m_ID == A );
    }

    bool operator!=( const U32_ID& A )  const
    {
        return ( this->m_ID == A.m_ID );
    }

    bool operator!=( const U32 A )      const
    {
        return ( this->m_ID == A );
    }

    // implicit convertion operator
    operator U32()                      const
    {
        return ( m_ID );
    }

protected:

    U32 m_ID;
} U32_ID;
```

Here `U32` is a 32-bit unsigned integer. Then for eacht new type, you can derive from the base class like so:

```
typedef struct Actor_ID : U32_ID
{
    explicit Actor_ID( U32 a ) : U32_ID( a ) {}
} Actor_ID;
```

Don't forget the `explicit` constructor. Now

```
void f(Actor_ID a){}
void main(){
    f(Actor_ID(5)); // OK
    f(5);           // Error: cannot implicitly convert int to Actor_ID
}
```

Comment: It is unusual to make the copy constructor implicit.